# Getting the error "Column Names have duplicates" when working with Magento

Tags: magento

I keep getting an error when I upload the spreadsheet I have on Magento, and I'm really not sure what's wrong. I'd be glad to fire the spreadsheet over if you'd like to take a look at it, but I really have no idea.

Comment: My guess is that you join 2 tables that contain the same column name.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Look for something like

```
Select A.*,B.*
inner join A.ID = B.ID
```

So you get two ID columns in the output

Need to make it something like

```
Select A.ID as AID, B.ID as BID
inner join A.ID = B.ID
```